# How to copy a char array in another char array(which is marshaled)

Tags: c#

I want to copy a char array of 64 which is a parameter from a method into a structure member, I use my struct as a Buffer, the member from the structure is also defined as a char array of 64 but it is marshaled. I tried using different methods but every time I copy this array, the value what it shows me is 00 00 00 ......  . Is there another way to copy this.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
protected struct TCommandParam
{
    public int IValue;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public char[] SValue;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 64)]
    public char[] FrameFD;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 16)]
    public char[] CRCProfile;
    public int TCanTime;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
protected struct TCommandBuffer
{
    public int Command;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 10)]
    public TCommandParam[] Param;
    public int ReturnValue;

    public TCommandBuffer(int tsize)
    {
        this.Command = 0;
        this.Param = new TCommandParam[tsize];
        this.ReturnValue = 0;
    }
}
```

This is the function where I want to copy.

```
public int CAN_TransmitSingleFD(int canNo, int iD, char[] frameFD)
{
    this.ReadBuffer();
    this.CANDIAG_CommandBufferInit();
    this.buff.Param[1].IValue = canNo;
    this.buff.Param[2].IValue = iD;
    this.buff.Param[3].FrameFD = frameFD;
    this.CANDIAG_Client_SendCommand(809);
    this.WriteBuffer();
    return this.CANDIAG_CommandBufferExit();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Indeed - a [mcve] please. (It's much easier to understand actual code than a description of code.)

Comment: I added my method and my structures.

Comment: This still isn't minimal or complete. Please provide a *complete* example which is *minimal* (we don't need to know the details of all the bits and pieces of your real code - we just need enough to reproduce the issue so we can try to fix it; but we should be able to copy/paste/compile/run to do that.)